# VBA determine linenumber in a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I get the linenumber of the selection in a TextBox?
Normaly I use Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber), but in a TextBox I allways get -1.
I can find out in which TextBox/Shape the cursor is:

```
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox And Selection.Range.InRange(shp.TextFrame.TextRange) Then
        MsgBox "The cursor is currently in shape: " & shp.Name
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next shp
MsgBox "The cursor is not currently in a shape with text."
```

So I hoped to use the shp in next step, e.g. with

```
shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
```

But there is my -1 again.
Has anyone an idea. Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

Comment: Someone voted up my question. It seems like it was solved, but it isn´t, it´s only my question. So please ignore the vote and help me. Thanks a lot! (Or I understand the vote up here in the wrong way. If so, then sorry.)

Comment: You've not understood. The upvote means someone likes your question.